# CentOS - how to tell IPtables block the world but only allow if they have unique url?

Tags: linux, centos, security, iptables, firewall

I have following iptables. But now i need to allow anyone in this server if he have an unique url: `www.example.com/IamEncodedencodedencodedencodedencodedencoded_Allow_Me`

```
$ yum install iptables-services
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# 1 ############ My office ##########
-A INPUT -s 217.1.2.3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 82.1.2.3 -j ACCEPT
############# My office END ######

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# 2 ########### Service center ############
-A INPUT -s 18.16.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
############ Service center END ############


-A INPUT -j DROP    
COMMIT

$ systemctl restart iptables
$ systemctl reload iptables
```

**EDIT:**

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 217.1.2.3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 82.1.2.3 -j ACCEPT    
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT    
-A INPUT -s 18.16.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -j DROP

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

Comment: Blocking urls is not iptables/netfilter related job.

Comment: NOT Blocking URLS you are not getting the point. The server is blocked from the world. But only allowed to open an url if its authorised (such as Google docs, excel share unique url to a report person via invitation)

Comment: Okie. Allowing urls is not iptables/netfilter related job.

Comment: No it has related job. Because IPtable has to block the world but only leave one TCP port open how?

Comment: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` I think this is the first example of any iptables tutorial.

Comment: Please see my EDIT section. Do i have to chronologically add that your line after the DROP or before DROP?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the access from the browser and you are using **Apache** as webserver, then you can add below lines in **Apache** configuration and start the service.

```
#Deny the access to everything first
<Location />
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from All
</Location>

# then allow access to specific URL
<Location /test.html>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from All
</Location>
```

If this is the case, this was answered earlier [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13803423/4164298)

Comment: Did you tried http://serverfault.com/a/220919/250067 ?